# Getting image resource from SVG (Vector) in PHP

Tags: php

I have been searching the web high and low looking for a way to generate an image resource for a vector(svg) image so I can do some image manipulation (Merging two vectors). I have yet to find a function or some sort of equivalent to `imagecreatefrompng` or `imagecreatefromjpeg`. Any help would be appreciated. I may just be going down the wrong path

Comment: does this help? http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7073-PHP-Create-and-edit-vectorial-graphics-in-SVG-files.html

Comment: Can [imagecreatefromString](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) help you?

Comment: SVG is supported natively by the Imagick module available for PHP.

Comment: @Martin Thanks. I was able to achieve the affect needed using CSS, and it's faster than making the request to the server to create and get the image

Comment: That's good news. Could you post an answer to your own question, so that others (like me) can see how you solved it and use a similar method?

Comment: @Martin: [imagecreatefromstring()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) only recognizes JPEG, PNG, GIF, WBMP, and GD2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the result I needed using CSS and javascript/jQuery

HTML

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://something.com/img1.png" class="img image1"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img{
    /*Set all images with this class to be on the top left of the screen*/
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:10px
}

.image1{
    z-index:1;
}

.image2{
    /*Make image 2 overlay image 1*/
    z-index:2;
}
```

Javascript

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var img2 = $('<img src="http://something.com/img2.png"/>')
    img2.addClass("img").addClass("image2")
    $(".image1").after(img2)
})
```